# Flutter Map markers not displaying

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class NewMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMapState createState() => _NewMapState();
}

class _NewMapState extends State<NewMap> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  Position position;

  Widget _child;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  BitmapDescriptor pinLocationIcon;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _child = SpinKitRipple(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: index.isEven ? Colors.grey : Color(0xffffb838),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    getCurrentLocation();
    populateClients();
    setCustomMapPin();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position res = await getCurrentPosition();
    setState(() {
      position = res;
      _child = mapWidget();
    });
  }

  populateClients() {
    
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('map').get().then((docs) {
      if (docs.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < docs.docs.length; ++i) {
          initMarker(docs.docs[i].data(), docs.docs[i].id);
           
        }
      }
      
    });
  }

  void initMarker(tomb, tombId) {
    var markerIdVal = tombId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(tomb['location'].latitude, tomb['location'].longitude),
      icon: pinLocationIcon,
      
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

  void setCustomMapPin() async {
    pinLocationIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5), 'assets/images/pin.png');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color(0xffffb838)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: _child,
    );
  }

  Widget mapWidget() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
              zoom: 10,
            ),
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              _controller = controller;
            },
            compassEnabled: true,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            
            ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 26,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code when i try to print on the console the lat long values are printed so that the values are read from the firestore.
The map is properly displaying the current location is also being displayed.
As i understand the markers are been created as i can get the lat long printed to the console
But the markers are not displaying on the map.

How can i solve this issue

Comment: code looks good; not sure this help, have your tried calling `mapWidget()` directly within Scaffold like `body: mapWidget()`

Comment: it is set in getCurrentLocation ```_child = mapWidget();```

Comment: yes, I noticed; but `setState()` reruns only build() method. since the _child is a class member and is assigned in initState(), just wanna give a try;

Comment: it was due to memory after ```flutter clean``` it displayed thank you a lot for your help and time

Comment: Great, you fixed! could you please post your answer? so that it will help other viewers.

Comment: one last thing ```infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Shop', snippet: tomb['list']),```  i want to display a list in the info window what datatype should i store in firestore and how can i adjust the infowindow.
I stored list as an array and used the above infowindow command but it didnt work

Comment: I am unable to get you clearly; why don't you ask a question in detail? you may get some experts suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is with the IDE, thanks to Muthu Thavamani I was able to identify that there are no bugs in the code.

It happens due to the built of of the application, after removing it the issue is being solved

Try

`flutter clean` command in the IDE terminal